# Error trying to add SVG image to xcode assets

Tags: xcode, svg, inkscape, xcasset

I have converted an image from PNG to SVG using the vectorizer.io website. The SVG image looks fine when viewed with the Chrome browser and in GIMP. But when I try to add it to the asset folder in xcode (Version 11.4.1) I get this error ...

*The SVG file provided for the symbol image set X is not suitable. Symbol image file (null) must have a glyph for regular weight Medium image size.*

I have tried opening the file with Inkscape and saving it as various versions of the SVG and PDF, but none seem to be acceptable.

I have not been able work out how to provide that glyph, and whether this is a fault in the SVG file or something I have failed to do in xcode.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? Ramis's answer is wholly unhelpful...

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. No I never did find a solution. I had to use a PNG file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Only starting from Xcode 12 you can use SVG.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error in Xcode 14.3.1 when I tried to add an SVG file via 'Symbol Image Set'. Then, I attempted to use 'Import,' and the SVG loaded. I think 'Symbol Image Set' works with SF Symbol templates only.

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UaIm.png)